# Can you see both Jupiter and Saturn (and their moons) in detail during their upcoming conjunction?

Tags: jupiter, saturn

In December of this year, Jupiter and Saturn are going to be in a conjunction. Are they going to be close enough that you could resolve both as more than just dots and see their respective satellites in the same FOV with a telescope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At their closest on the 21th of December (in the UK), they will be very close, only about 6 arc minutes.  That is in the field of view of most telescopes (about 1/5 of the diameter of the moon.

It will look like this (simulated)

[image]

Comment: However, won't they be close to the Sun? So telescopic view would be much different than a typical night time view.

Comment: Quite close yes, but this view is at 17:30 local time, which is well after sunset at my location